# Undefined method for 'people' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can't seem to understand why I get this error message when I try to call count on my method? Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Statistics</h2>
<hr />

<h3 class="total-number">Total Signups: <%= @engaged %></h3>
<h3 class='total-number'> All Subscribed People: <%= @person %></h3>
<hr />
<p class='total-number'> Visitor group: <%= @visitor.people.count %></p>
<p class='total-number'> Dance group: <%= @dance.people.count %></p>
<p class='total-number'> Staff group: <%= @staff.people.count %></p>
<p class='total-number'> Volunteer group: <%= @volunteer.people.count %></p>
<hr />
<p><%= link_to "Send Message", root_path %></p>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
  def subscribed_num
   @person = Person.subscribed.count
   @engaged = Person.count
   @dance = Group.find_by(name: "dance")
   @visitor = Group.find_by(name: "visitor")
   @volunteer = Group.find_by(name: "volunteer")
   @staff = Group.find_by(name: "staff")
  end
```

It seems straight forward but I'm probably doing something small wrong.

Comment: Your find_by for Dance, Visitor, Volunteer, or Staff returned no results so `@dance`, `@visitor`, `@volunteer`, or `@staff` is nil.

Comment: You are correct, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group.find_by(name: 'something')` will return `nil` if there's no Group matching the name.

So one of visitor, dance, staff or volunteer seems to not exist.

One way to handle such situations is to use a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to represent the absence of a group.

A null group could always have an empty array of people.

Here's an example using the excellent [Naught gem](https://github.com/avdi/naught) written by Avdi Grimm:

```
NullGroup = Naught.build do |builder|
  def people
    []
  end
end

# controller
def subscribed_num
  @person = Person.subscribed.count
  @engaged = Person.count
  @dance = Group.find_by(name: "dance") || NullGroup.new
  @visitor = Group.find_by(name: "visitor") || NullGroup.new
  @volunteer = Group.find_by(name: "volunteer") || NullGroup.new
  @staff = Group.find_by(name: "staff") || NullGroup.new
end
#
```